# How to get XML to Map of Objects in Java using jaxb?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an xml like

```
<nodes>
 <node>
    <id/>
    <name/>
 </node>
 <node>
    <id/>
    <name/>
 </node>
</nodes>
```

so I wanted to know is it possible to unmarshall this is as a map of objects with key as node id using jaxb?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this using an xml adapter. Let's say you got Nodes bean as

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class Nodes {
        @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(NodesToMapAdapter.class)
        public List<Node> nodes;

        public List<Node> getNodes() {
            return nodes;
        }

        public void setNodes(List<Node> nodes) {
            this.nodes = nodes;
        }
    }
```

Then to get a Map of nodes (by id) from the list of nodes you can write a simple adapter for example as below.

```
public class NodesToMapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<List<Node>, Map<String, Node>> {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Node> unmarshal(List<Node> v) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Node> nodesMap = new HashMap<String, Node>();
        for(Node n: v)
        {
            nodesMap.put(n.getId(), n);
        }
        return nodesMap;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Node> marshal(Map<String, Node> v) throws Exception {
        //create a list of nodes using the map of nodes
        return null;
    }
}
```

The `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(NodesToMapAdapter.class)` annotation does the magic, it directs the `JAXB` marshaller and unmarshaller to `NodesToMapAdapter` when processing the Nodes objects. BTW there are a bunch of SO questions and answers on this topic.